# Помогите удалить первичный ключ в таблице базы firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

Необходимо в сотнях баз изменить тип поля, но на это поле повешен первичный ключ, соответственно его необходимо удалить перед изменением. Однако имена этих ключей в разных базах разное. В каких-то оно именованное, в каких-то автоматически назначенное. В общем не угадать.

Немного покапавшись в системных таблицах, обнаружил, что все первичные ключи собраны в RDB$Relation_Constraint, где в поле RDB$Constraint_name указан искомое имя ключа, а в поле RDB$relation_name искомая таблица.

Пытался вычистить таблице от первичных ключей путем выполнения запроса (писал по памяти, мог немного опечататься в названиях полей:

```
execute block
as
    declare variable tblname varchar(32);
    declare variable pkname varchar(32);
begin
    for select rdb$relation_name, rdb$constraint_name from rdb$relation_constraint
    where trim(rdb$relation_name) = 'MYTABLE'
    into :tblname, :pkname
    do
    begin
        execute statament 'alter table '|| trim(:tblname) || ' drop constraint ' || trim(:pkname);
    end
end
```

при таком выполнении выпадает ошибка:

```
this operation is not defined for system tables.
unsuccessful metadata update.
ERASE RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINT failed.
action cancelled by trigger (2) to preserve data integrity.
Column used in a PRIMARY constraint must be NOT NULL
```

При этом, если взять запрос который формируется в строке execute statement '...' то он выполняется корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в `WHERE` дополнительное условие `AND RDB$CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'`

Сама таблица `rdb$relation_constraint` содержит все ограничения, в т.ч. и `NOT NULL`, который, судя по ошибке, вы пытаетесь удалить раньше первичного ключа.

Comment: да, вы правы, в обратном порядке удаление проходит корректно.